# Show that $10^n$ has $(n+1)^2$ positive divisors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I made that observation earlier while doing an exercise in an elementary book about combinatorics. I have no knowledge of number theory what so ever, so just wondering if there is a simple proof of this. Tried using induction but with no success. As you can see this is true for the first 8 numbers.[image]

Comment: **Hint** What is the prime factorization of $10^n$?

Comment: Hint: (expands the hint of @Travis) if $n=p_1^{k_1}...p_{m}^{k_m}$ is the prime factorization of $n$, then $n$ has $(k_1+1)(k_2+1)...(k_m+1)$ divisors by an easy counting argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$10^n=2^n 5^n$. Since $2$ and $5$ are primer numbers,  both $2^n$ and $5^n$ have $(n+1)$ positive divisors. So you have $(n+1)^2$ positive divisors for $10^n$.